# Git workflow with a single NON-git teammate

Tags: git, git-branch

- ***Example 1:*** Three teammates are on a git-controlled project. A new member is joining the team, who is doesn't know/use git yet.
- ***Example 2:*** There is a "stray" uncontrolled copy of a project with changes and additions, but without the version data (for instance, a copy of a project from a live server, which had it's own course).

What is the most sensible way to allow non-version-controlled changes to exist in the workflow and/or to import them to the trunk?

Comment: My intuition is to simply give him a new branch and update his files manually and do his commits myself but I am not sure what the caveats are.

Comment: If your new teammate is learning git… Why not teach him/her how to clone? Then they can make changes to their clone.

Comment: Why don't you teach the new member git? It might take a while, but if he or she is going to be a part of the team for a few weeks or longer, it will likely be worth it. And if he or she is already a professional developer, honestly, git isn't that hard for a programmer to pick up.

Comment: A complex project already has a steep learning curve for a newcomer. Adding GIT to the list might prove counter-productive, even disruptive, since we have an established workflow and the newbie has to prioritize very specific tasks rather than learn a new VCS.
He will have to join in on the git fun eventually, just not right away.

Comment: Then document the "established workflow", including the specific `git` invocations needed to accomplish each task, and possibly including the rationale behind each invocation. That will form a reasonable foundation for learning the basics of `git`, and more detailed knowledge can be built up later.

Comment: You are right, that will work perfectly. I will however amend the question, just to stay true to the "no git whatsoever" interest, since I feel we strayed from my question to my specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to integrate a stray uncontrolled copy, which does include modifications of its own is:

- to have access to its content through a shared path
- use the `git --work-tree` option in order to do a `git add` of said stray content into a local repo.

That is

```
cd /path/to/local/git/repo
git checkout -b stray # dedicated branch
git --work-tree=/shared/path/to/stray/content add .
git commit -m "import stray content"
```

You get a dedicated branch with the stray content in it (you can repeat the process to record multiple changes of that external content)

You can later proceed merging that branch into your main branch if you want.

At the same time, collaborators can keep making changes directly to the stray content, without using git: each `git add` instance will automatically detect changed, deleted or new files.